# Специфика комментирования php кода

Tags: php

Раньше не приходилось так делать но заметил что у многих программистов комментирование такого формата

```
class Test {
     /**
      * @get_test
     */
   public function get_test($type) {
     // ну или так вот

    /* @var $type_region type */
     $type_region = $type;
  }


}
```

какой смысл несут такие комментарии, кроме информативного?

Comment: Для формирования документации по коду.  По аналогии с Javadoc https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHPDoc
Отличительная особенность, это начало комментария с двух символов '**'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Изначально это были источники данных для генерации документации, теперь это чаще подсказки типа для IDE. Если в PHPStorm написать такую конструкцию:

```
/** @type SplFileInfo $item */
foreach (retrieveArray() as $item) {
    ...
}
```

То внутри foreach будет применяться автодополнение для $item, потому что IDE будет знать, что в $item лежит SPlFileInfo. Аналогично можно помечать функции и методы, чтобы предоставить информацию о том, что они могут вернуть.

Полная спека PHPDoc-аннотаций [здесь](https://github.com/phpDocumentor/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/phpdoc.md) (пока не принята, может измениться). Отмечу, что в последние несколько лет практика расширилась до использования аннотаций вообще в целом, и с их помощью задаются метаданные символов языка.